# Why was Electric flux defined and why the way it was?

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

The wikipedia definition

> Electric flux is the measure of the electric field through a given
> surface,
>
> More formally ,The electric flux $\Phi$ through a given surface $S$ is
> defined to be $$ \Phi=\int_S \mathbf E\cdot\mathrm d \mathbf S. $$

Firstly ,why is there a need to define such a quantity i.e what exaclty is it measuring and in what terms?

-? **Is it measuring the strength of electric field per unit area ,if so ,what exactly does it mean**,I take Electric field value at a point to mean force that a unit charge would experience if we were to place it at that point ,and in Electric field created by an Electric charge we assign every point of space with some value.

> **What exactly is Flux measuring ,not what it is analogous to ,but what's it measuring** ,Is it the strength of force a surface area feels due to electric field
> if a we were to put a surface of certain are in that electric field

W**hat does intensity of electric field per unit area means**, is it the same as current intensity just without the charge flowing part *i.e measuring rate of flow of charges through a surface  that would be there cause of the electric field if we were to place charges there ?*

Also ,what are the caveats when explaining flux as number of Electric fields lines,like do all lines need to be of equal magnitude and such and why such representation is used to explain div and curl ?

Is there a similar analogy for vector representation of Electric field ,assigning each point with arrows ,its length representing magnitude and its orientation representing the direction of effect of force

**Flux is often explain through analogy of flow but that analogy makes other concepts for me slightly awkward to understand cause of the difference in treatment to how we define them.**

Electric field  ,Electric potential all have formal and pretty intuitive explanation that are also technically correct  ,Is there one for Electric flux?

How exacly does the idea of flux help us define Divergence and curl ,Is **flux** even neccesary?

Comment: "I take Electric field value at a point to mean force that a unit positive charge would experience if we were to place it at that point". I think you may be conflating the definition of the direction of the electric field at a point, which is the direction of the force that a positive test charge would experience if placed at that point, with the magnitude of the force that any charge, positive or negative, would experience if placed in the field, namely F=QE

Comment: I took the convention of representing it w.r.t positive unit charge

Answer (score 0):

> Is it measuring the strength of electric field per unit area

No, the opposite. If the field is uniform, it measure the strength of the electric field multiplied by the area (with a factor for how well the field is aligned with the normal vector to the area).

Speaking crudely, it sums up the "number of electric field lines" passing through the area.

> why is there a need to define such a quantity

One very basic one is that if S is a closed surface enclosing a charged particle (or even zero charged particles), this value (the total flux exiting the surface) doesn't change if we change the size or shape of the surface, so long as we keep the quantity of charge enclosed constant. (i.e. it's the important quantity in the integral form of Gauss's Law)

> what are the caveats when explaining flux as number of Electric fields lines,like do all lines need to be of equal magnitude

Yes, we need to assume that each field line represents an equal amount of flux, and that the density of the lines is proportional to the electric field strength. At some level we need to assume the field lines are drawn with small enough resolution (each line represents a small enough amount of flux) to have a large number of lines in any patch of surface we wish to consider.

> Is there a similar analogy for vector representation of Electric field

The field lines are just the same as the electric field vectors, but connected up to form paths along the direction of the field vectors (and drawn with density representing field strength).

Put another way, the vectors are just representations of the electric field lines at individual points along their paths.

> and such and why such representation is used to explain div and curl ?

Because many students (and practioners) find it easier to visualize and comprehend field lines than more abstract representations of the electric field. If you prefer a more symbolic or abstract representation, then there's no need for you to particularly worry about field lines, except as a tool to communicate with others.

Comment: i don;t really get what's it that flux measuring ,not what it is analogous to ,but what's it measuring

Comment: @Anuj, it's measuring something that is (usefully) invariant as you change the shape of the surface but keep the same amount of charge enclosed. If you want to think of it that way, it's measuring the amount of charge enclosed.

Comment: That's the implication we can derive through what its measuring ,like said the number of field lines as analogy ,amount of charge is just somethinf we can derive through its measurement ,its not the initial measurement